# When is $\int_0^{2a} f= 2 \int_0^a f$?

Tags: definite-integrals

When (for what kind of $f$ and e.g. $a \in \mathbb{R}$) is $$\int_0^{2a} f= 2 \int_0^a f$$?

With some trigonometric functions ($a=\pi$)?

Comment: For all $a$? Very rarely. For some $a$? Quite frequently.

Comment: Should hold for the cases when $f(x + a) = f(x)\ \forall x,\ a\in\mathbb{R}$, but there may well be others

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ continuous and differentiate with respect to $a$:
$$
2f(2a)=\frac{d}{da}\int_0^{2a}f=2\int_0^a f=2f(a).
$$
Thus, $f(2a)=f(a)=f(2^{-1}a)=\cdots=f(2^{-n}a)\to f(0)$, due to continuity.

Thus $f(a)=f(0)$, for all $a$, and finally $f$ has to be constant..

Answer (score -1):

Both $ \sin^2(x) $, $ \sin(2x) $ will work.

Comment: True .... but more of a comment